# Facebook deep linking using Applinks for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, applinks

Hey please can you share app link working tutorial as i cant open my app using facebook. I am waiting for your positive response and looking forward for your helping hand.

Thanks

Comment: try to google first and if you don't find then ask here. you will get the first result on google to answer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls go through  the document of Facebook for this or use [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios)

or 
https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10151871746615582

Comment: Hi Rohit
Thanks , But very poor facebook documentation. Have you done it using app links?

Comment: pls go through this : http://applinks.org/documentation/

Comment: Hi Rohit,
Yes , I have tried that also. Still not working...

Comment: i have used deep linking not app links

Comment: In deep linking , What should be og:url ??

Answer (score 0):

Try Googling, this is the first result I got:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios

Comment: Hi 

Thanks for your valuable suggestion.